# Conditional splitting a string at space

Tags: r

My input vector is

```
'salesman snow "rain check" "Radio shack"'
```

The answer I am looking for is

```
"salesman"    "snow"        "rain check"  "Radio shack"
```

tried

```
  strsplit(vector, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
> gsub('"', '', regmatches(vector, gregexpr('"[^\\"]*"|(\\S+)',  vector))[[1]])
[1] "salesman"    "snow"        "rain check"  "Radio shack"
```